# Windows Vista Recovery partition is Primary Drive (c:)

Tags: windows-vista, partition

i've been given a laptop at work to stick Office 2010 on it. I've never seen this laptop before and just noticed that the RECOVERY drive is the c: drive. The d: drive is the hard drive.

The thing is i cant rename the RECOVERY to be the d: and the other to be the c: because they both contain the OS (vista)

Advice please? Never came across this issue before!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wont give me an option. But never mind solved it anyway. Turns out someone hadn't removed an old windows installation! Removed it, problem solved!

Answer (score 1):

So, what is your problem? Install it on Drive D: and be done with it. These days, most modern programs handle this without an issue, only very old installers behave strange sometimes.

Comment: It wont give me an option. But never mind solved it anyway. Turns out someone hadn't removed an old windows installation! Removed it, problem solved!

Comment: @benhowdle89 You can post that as an answer and mark it accepted, that's perfectly allowed.